# Issue installing Scrapy using Python 3.11 on Windows 11

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, scrapy, pipenv

I'm using Windows 11, Python 3.10.1. I created a virtual environment using `venv`, and installed scrapy, and all requirements.  **Everything worked perfectly!** Then I installed Python 3.11.1, created a virtual environment using `venv`, installed scrapy, and I received an error:

```
  Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport
Failed to build twisted-iocpsupport
ERROR: Could not build wheels for twisted-iocpsupport, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

### Issue of concern

I already had Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 installed on my device, and I was able to run scrapy 2.7.1 successfully using Python 3.10.  I only experienced this issue with Python 3.11.

### Mitigation attempts

1. Installed a fresh copy of Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 from the website ~ **No resolve.** ❌
2. Uninstalled, reinstalled Python 3.11 ensuring `PATH` was installed ~ **No resolve.** ❌
3. Created a virtual environment using `pipenv`, and Python 3.11. Same error as using `venv` ~ **no resolve.** ❌
4. Created a virtual environment using `venv`, and Python 3.10 ~ **Scrapy works!**  ✅
5. Created a virtual environment using `pipenv`, and Python 3.10 ~ **Scrapy works!**  ✅

So it seems like this is specific to Python 3.11 perhaps. So, right now I am back to using Python 3.10 for Scrapy projects.

### Question

How can I resolve this issue, and use Python 3.11 for Scrapy projects?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Did you try reading the scrapy documentation, in order to see whether 3.11 is supported? Is it? Are you able to install other libraries in a 3.11 venv? Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not tech support. If the purpose is to ask whether this is supported, or to complain that it is not, the appropriate place for that is on a scrapy bug tracker, forum, etc.

Comment: Separately: Did you try looking up the `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.` error message? It seems to be a very common one.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you.

Look at the error message, as it says:

```
D:\Users\80362386>python --version Python 3.11.1 Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in d:\users\80362386\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography<40,>=38.0.0->pyopenssl>=21.0.0->twisted[tls]) (2.21) Building wheels for collected packages: twisted-iocpsupport   Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport Failed to build twisted-iocpsupport ERROR: Could not build wheels for twisted-iocpsupport, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I solved this problem by installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater

I download vs_BuildTools.exe, and I install the first option, then the problem solved.

I think you might double check whether your Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0  installed successfully?